# JPA CriteriaQuery: fields of the object doesn't mapped

Tags: java, jpa

Good day. I try to select rows from table with CriteriaQuery.

I have an object `Card`:

```
@Entity(name = "bank_cards")
public class Card {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private int id;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cards")
  private Set<Account> accounts;

  private String number;
  private float amount;
  private String expire;
  private String type;

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
  }

  public float getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }

  public void setAmount(float amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
  }

  public String getExpire() {
    return expire;
  }

  public void setExpire(String expire) {
    this.expire = expire;
  }

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public Set<Account> getAccounts() {
    return accounts;
  }

  public void setAccounts(Set<Account> accounts) {
    this.accounts = accounts;
  }
}
```

Select rows using CriteriaQuery:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("cards");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

CriteriaQuery<Card> cq = cb.createQuery(Card.class);
Metamodel m = em.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Card> Card_ = m.entity(Card.class);

Root<Card> card = cq.from(Card.class);
cq.where(card.get(Card_.number)); // error
```

At the last string field `number` not found.

Linked unit in persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="users" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>main.java.entities.User</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="java" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="java" />

      <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically -->
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

I need to execute next query:

```
"SELECT * FROM bank_cards WHERE number='" + cardNumber + "'"
```

cardNumber - string

Metamodel class:

```
@StaticMetamodel(Card.class)
public class Card_ {
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<Card, Integer> id;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<Card, String> number;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<Card, String> expire;
  public static volatile SingularAttribute<Card, String> type;

  public static volatile SingularAttribute<Card, Float> amount;

  public static volatile SetAttribute<Card, Account> accounts;
}
```

Comment: Show us your metamodel Card_ class.

Comment: @PaulWasilewski i've added it above now

Comment: Error stacktrace?

Comment: @jklee there are no stacktrace, this code just not compiles, error on trying to get any field of `Card`, field not found message on mouse over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your predicate is wrong.

```
public Card byNumber(String number) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Card> cq = cb.createQuery(Card.class);

    Root<Card> card = cq.from(Card.class);
    Predicate equalPredicate = cb.equal(card.get(Card_.number), number);
    cq.where(equalPredicate);
    cq.select(card);
    return em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: But it's not a criteriaQuery :D So, thank you anyway :)

Comment: It's 100% percent a criteriaQuery. Why not?

Comment: Oh, really. Don't know, why i decided otherwise. Sorry. Just saw `createQuery` that also exists for `EntityManager`... Sorry. And thank you again!